# How to use gatsby-image for markdown content from Strapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, strapi

Is it possible to optimize images in markdown content from Strapi (rendered with `react-markdown`) using `gatsby-image`?

Note, `gatsby-remark-images` doesn't work for such a case.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment: No. There is a pull request addressing that but it is there for a long time and I'm not sure if it will be implemented. I know they are working on it but no ETA